# Mongodb aggregate use field reference

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Data:

```
{
   "_id": "test1",
   "orderStatus": "shipped",
   "history": {
      "pending": {startAt: '2021/03/16'},
      "shipped": {startAt: '2021/03/18'},
   }
}
```

Is it possible to access sub document by another field?

I'd like to get current order status startAt in an aggregation pipeline, for example:

```
db.aggregate([{$addFields: { currentStartAt: "history.$orderStatus" }}])
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use `currentStartAt: "$history.orderStatus"` and you should **never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw. Use proper `Date` objects.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work, "$history.orderStatus" not exist

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { history: { $objectToArray: "$history" } } },
   { $set: { history: { $filter: { input: "$history", cond: { $eq: ["$orderStatus", "$$this.k"] } } } } },
   { $project: { currentStartAt: { $first: "$history.v.startAt" } } }
])
```

Within a mongo shell you can also do this one:

```
var field = db.collection.findOne({}, { orderStatus: 1 }).orderStatus;
var field = "$history." + field + ".startAt";
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $project: { currentStartAt: field } }
])
```

Comment: This query is working, but with too much performance cost in a huge collection. I'd like to access directly the field by a dynamic reference based on another field. If no one is going to give a better answer I'm going to accept this

Answer (score 0):

This also works but I have no idea about performance, let me know how it performs.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    "$addFields": {
    "currentStartAt": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
        {
            "$map": {
            "input": {
                "$filter": {
                "input": {
                    "$objectToArray": "$history"
                },
                "as": "el",
                "cond": {
                    "$eq": [
                    "$orderStatus",
                    "$$el.k"
                    ]
                }
                }
            },
            "in": "$$this.v.startAt"
            }
        },
        0
        ]
    }
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
    "currentStartAt": 1
    }
}
])
```

Another query doing same thing

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
        "currentStartAt": {
            "$filter": {
            "input": {
                "$objectToArray": "$history"
            },
            "cond": {
                "$eq": [
                "$orderStatus",
                "$$this.k"
                ]
            }
            }
        }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
        "currentStartAt": {
            "$first": "$currentStartAt.v.startAt"
        }
        }
    }
])
```